# Не получается получить переменную в JSON (PYTHON)

Tags: python, json

**nicks.txt**

```
{
    "players": {
        "name": "users",
        "user_319990365": [
            {
                "id": 319990365,
                "nick": "developer"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Как получить "nick"?**

пытался сделать так... (извините, если очень коряво :D )

**main.py**

```
async def check_nick(id_member=319990365):
    with open('nicks.txt') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for x in data['players']:
            for y in x['user_{0}'.format(id_member)]:
                return y
```

,но выскакивала ошибка:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл с итерацией по 'players' не нужен. Кроме того, не нужен **async**, потому что нету асинхронных операций. И да, безусловный **return** на первой же итерации второго цикла выглядел довольно странно — заменил на **yield** для примера.

```
def check_nick(id_member=319990365):
    with open('nicks.txt') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for y in data['players']['user_{0}'.format(id_member)]:
            yield y['nick']
```

---

Хм... но если немного подумать, кажется, у вас в исходных данных есть ошибка. Если 'players' был бы массивом в `[]`, то тогда ваши исходные циклы сработали бы.

Comment: а если бы, `players` был бы массив? Что тогда делать? Мой метод не работает...

Comment: @fixees__ значит что-то не так делаете - у меня он работает https://gist.github.com/mymedia2/89807b3f81cd79e7e6a45c922340fce4

Comment: оказывается, я немного попутал с названием файла :D уже работает, благодарю